# Correctly gradually decreasing values in a grid

Tags: java, grid, minecraft

I'm making a program to use when playing Minecraft, it's a grid that simulates a floor and what I want to do is be able to dot out obstacles and lights and calculate what "blocks" would get sufficient amount of light. It's a planningtool, so you get an overview of the floor and make something pretty with sufficient lightning.

I can dot out the obstacles and the light, creating the correct spread but my problem lies with the nature of the problem I wanted to solve with this program, I mess up alot and have to redo everything so I want to be able to remove lights and also, of course, the light that light would emit.

The code for the lightcalculation when you dot out a light.

```
public void changeLightUp(int light)
    {           
        //no light left, return
        if(light == 0)
            return;

        //not a source or block, change light
        if(type == 0)
        {
            //light is greater, return
            if(lightLevel >= light)             
                return;
            lightLevel = light;
        }
        //solid block, ignore
        else if(type == 1)
            return;

        if(xCoord != main.gridSizeX - 1)
            main.grid[xCoord + 1][yCoord].changeLightUp(light-1);
        if(xCoord > 0)
            main.grid[xCoord - 1][yCoord].changeLightUp(light-1);
        if(yCoord != main.gridSizeY - 1)            
            main.grid[xCoord][yCoord + 1].changeLightUp(light-1);
        if(yCoord > 0)              
            main.grid[xCoord][yCoord - 1].changeLightUp(light-1);
    }
```

So what this does is: I check if there's any light left (the method is recursive, so I send the light onto the next block, minus 1), then I check if it's a "floor" block, as long as the new light is greater - update. If it's not an obstacle I send the light (minus 1) to the four adjacent blocks until everything is done.

I cannot think of a good way to do this "backwards", this can't be the first problem of this sort so I'm sure the answer is out there! Don't have any idea what to search for though. Sorry if the answer is lying around all over the net :)

Edit:
It seemed I wasn't clear enough about the actual problem.
The grid consists of "blocks", each block carry it's own lightlevel. When a source is added to the grid, it "emits" light to it's neigbours, this is done by a recursive method that can be seen in the code-snippet.
The problem was that when I would delete a block, I didn't know how to remove the light in a correct way, it would be easy to simply calculate the blocks that was "hit" by the source but that doesn't take in account that there may exist other sources nearby so that the lightlevel would be wrong if I just set everything to 0.
Hope that cleared things up, and again thanks to all awesome people that answers to my questions <3

Comment: *"I cannot think of a.."* ..question?  If you can, please add it as an edit.

Comment: Hi Andrew! Orabig down here gave a solution, but I'll try and edit in a more clear question for further readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 solutions :

- You can add a `lightSourceId` attribute to your block class. This way, it will be possible to find all the blocks that are lit by the light Source you just switched off
- You can recalculate all the grid each time you change (add/delete/move) any light source.

Comment: Thanks! I went with the recalculate the whole grid approach :) not as efficient maybe, but it's for my own needs so no need for "good" code, your first suggestion would be the prettier choice.